# What's the most accurate way to get timed actions on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I want to have something happen about 6 times a second, consistently and accurately.  I tried setting an NSTimer, but it had very low accuracy and consistency.  What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here [How Do I write a Timer in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519562/how-do-i-write-a-timer-in-objective-c) it appears that NSTimer is not an high resolution timer

Comment: yeah but i need it to fire a selector six times a second.  and its not.

Comment: you can use those methods to compute a high resolution time difference and after the delta of time is higher of your threshold you can fire your action

Comment: well what im actually trying to do is make a strobe light.  ive seen other apps do it and just wanted to try it.  i duno why but the method that turns the light on and off must be too slow or something because it's very unreliable when i strobe it.  i say to call it every .5 seconds and sometimes its on longer than others, sometimes it takes a while to get going, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use ticks instead?

```
_animationTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingTimer(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Convert.ToInt64(AnimationInterval * 10000000l)), MainLoop);
```