# NSTimer some times getting fired before the fire date?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nstimer

I'm setting up a timer to fire at an interval of 13 mins. But the timer seems to be getting fired at irregular intervals. This is an intermittent issue. Some users reported the issue and I'm not able to reproduce the same.

```
- (void)resetIdleTimer
{
    if (_idleTimer)
    {
        [_idleTimer invalidate];
        [_idleTimer release];
        _idleTimer = nil;
    }

    _idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:13*60.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:NO] retain];
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded
{
        // do some processing
    [_idleTimer release];
    _idleTimer = nil;
}
```

Timer will be reset (resetIdleTimer) depending on some conditions, but that's anyhow resets the timer with 13 mins.

When I looked into code, I can see only the issue that is not passing timer parameter to the selector. I'm not sure whether that's the reason for this issue or not ? Did anyone come across this kind of weird ness ? (Any how I will be updating the code to to have timer as an argument).
One user reported that its just happened after 4 mins itself.

Comment: I also faced this issue. So I used cancel previous method after timer complete. In this timer will not repeat.

Comment: @Matthias: he uses retain...

Comment: where and how do you declare _idleTimer?

Comment: my mistake, disregard that comment, I missed that retain.

Comment: I declared it in my interface file with in {} as     NSTimer *_idleTimer;

Answer (score 1):

Let confirm one thing,not passing timer parameter to the selector will not cause any issues.

Here is the updated code which works fine

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSTimer *myTimer;
```

or

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSTimer *myTimer;
```

**Methods**

```
- (void)resetIdleTimer
{

  if ([self.myTimer isValid]) 
        [self.myTimer invalidate];

   self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:13*60.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
} 
- (void)idleTimerExceeded
{
  NSLog(@"tiggered");
}
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong, its not going to reset the timer. resetIdleTimer always creates the new timer?(Which is not the expected behavior)

Comment: Its creates a timer and u don't want to care about the ownership of timer. What you want to do ? worrying with timer object memory ? or some thing else ?

Comment: When resetIdleTimer called, I want to reset the earlier timer and setup new with new interval.

Comment: oh.. I see.. okay.. then I will post the answer soon,,'

Comment: I have updated the answer,, It should work.. btwn I got a - vote before my edit.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't do - vote. Let me update the code and verify your answer.

Comment: dont forget the answer too :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after analyzing, I came to know that the code prior to [timer release], in idleTimerExceeded: creating the new timer (calling resetIdleTimer:) which itself releasing the same instance without invalidating it which causes resetIdleTimer to create another instance.  So  the timer instance which is released is getting called when its firedate is arrived.

Comment: work with ARC,thats better. u don't want to worry about the memory stuffs. One more comment, if u declare a property as "retain" and allocating new memories to it, it automatically release the old memory and assign new one.thats the @property implementation do.If u have more questions, feel free to ask.. if my answer helped u, feel free to accept the answer.. :) I wrote answer ARC-enabled mode.

Answer (score 0):

i don't find any error in your code, the only idea about is that a user enter your class creating an instance, let's call it instance "A", then start the timer, then exit your class before 13 minutes, then enter again with a new instance "B", a new timer starts...

at this point user expects your timer methods fires after 13 minutes... but timer of "A" is still pending (because there may be an error in the way you close your class) and executes...

You may try to add some logs and try to do as i said, and check all logs (in particular if you enter the dealloc, and that the log in idleTimerExceeded print instances equals to the last instances printed in resetIdleTimer):

```
    -(void)resetIdleTimer  {
            if (_idleTimer)
            {
                [_idleTimer invalidate];
                [_idleTimer release];
                _idleTimer = nil;
            }

            NSLog(@"...resetIdleTimer: instance: %p", self);
            _idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:13*60.0
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:NO] retain];
             NSLog(@"...resetIdleTimer: _idleTimer: %p", _idleTimer);
       }

        - (void)idleTimerExceeded
        {
                // do some processing
            NSLog(@"...idleTimerExceeded: instance: %p", self);
            NSLog(@"...idleTimerExceeded: _idleTimer: %p", _idleTimer);

            [_idleTimer release];
            _idleTimer = nil;
        }


        -(void) dealloc 
        {
            NSLog(@"...dealloc: instance: %p", self);
            [super dealloc];

        }
```

just an idea... but you may have forgotten that timers retain the instance passed in `target:`parameter (you pass "self", so your class instance is retained), so a common error is to forget to close the timer when closing the class instance.

a correct way should be:

-a root class (AAA) instantiate your class (BBB) with timer
-BBB start its timer
-AAA wanna dealloc/resetIdleTimer class BBB: before to release it must stop/invalidate BBB.timer (if not timer retain BBB, and BBB won't be released until timer fires/executes its method)

so, if it's your case... add a method that could be called from class AAA that stop/invalidate the timer, something like:

```
-(void)stopTimer{
                if (_idleTimer)
                {
                    [_idleTimer invalidate];
                    [_idleTimer release];
                    _idleTimer = nil;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your timer to fire in exact 13 minutes, maybe this will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519913/1226304