# Create Simple Timer in IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

How can I create a simple timer which will give me simply the **Time** in **millisecond**. Something like the following...

```
Timer *timer = [Timer alloc] init];
[timer start];   //Which will start from Zero
[timer pause];   //Which will Pause timer
[timer stop];    //Which will stop the timer
[timer getCurrentTime];  //Which will give me time elapsed in millisecond since [timer start] is called
```

**NSTimer** doesn't seem to Work as it provides more functionality but not this. Can I get this functionality using NSTimer? What would be the best way to achieve this?

**NOTE:** I don't want to call any function at any specific time period but just want the milliseconds since the timer started.

Comment: Did you tried anything ? Why don't you need to call another method ? If you call another method at specific time, you can get the time easily. Why are you doing it in a difficult way as there is an easy way?

Comment: `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:someDateInPast];`

Comment: You want a wrapper around an array that keeps instances of [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) objects. The first NSDate in the array is the start date. The second NSDate is the time when you paused the timer, the third NSDate is the time when you resumed the timer. The last NSDate is the time when you stopped your timer.

Comment: What to specify in the TimeInterval option of NSTimer as i want to run this infinitely untill i release the timer. also their is no repeat should be..

Comment: @MAtthias Bauch  I tried this. it works but i am looking for something simpler as requirement is very simple. Thanks for Your response

Comment: Please people, leave a comment if you downvote stating the reason so that we can improve the question.

Comment: The downvotes mean "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i Was looking for this but somehow i missed this question

[How Do I write a Timer in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519562/how-do-i-write-a-timer-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a timer for that?
Just store the start time and subtract it from the current time when you stop measuring:

```
static NSTimeInterval startTime;
static BOOL isRunning;
- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender
{
    if(!isRunning)
    {
        startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        isRunning = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%f", ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime) * 1000.0);
        isRunning = NO;
    }
}
```