# Delayed animation when a pan gesture leaves a UIView, with debouncing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Are there one or two idiomatic ways to handle the kind of UI interaction described below?  Perhaps a custom class is unnecessary?

I am implementing drag and drop in an iPadd app and would like to handle the case where the draggable is not released upon the droppable and the pan gesture leaves the `UIView`.

- The view expands and gets a border when the draggable is over it, and it will return to its previous size and lose the border when the draggable leaves the area. There will be a noticeable delay before the down-scale animation begins.
- It is possible the draggable will be brought back over the zone before the scale-down animation begins, suggesting the need for some kind of [debouncing](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), i.e., something to collect the events that occur within a period of time and treat them as one event.
- I know a large number of events are fired off during a pan gesture, and I don't want to allocate unnecessary resources (e.g., timers).

I was thinking of using a single custom timer, perhaps along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519562/how-do-i-write-a-timer-in-objective-c), but perhaps there's something much simpler for this?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will inflate the view with inflate-animation of 300ms whenever a finger moves over the view and will deflate the view back to normal whenever the touch is outside. No panGestureRecognizerRequired.

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
{
    BOOL hasExpanded;
    CGRect initialFrame;
    CGRect inflatedFrame;
}
@end

@implementation CustomView
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        hasExpanded = NO;

        initialFrame = frame;

        CGFloat inflateIncrement = 50.0f;

        inflatedFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x-(inflateIncrement*0.5f),
                                        self.frame.origin.y-(inflateIncrement*0.5f),
                                        self.frame.size.width+inflateIncrement,
                                        self.frame.size.height+inflateIncrement);

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)forceDeflate
{
    if (hasExpanded)
    {
        //start deflating view animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.frame = initialFrame;

        }];
        hasExpanded = NO;
    }
}


-(void)inflateByCheckingPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint
{
    if(!hasExpanded)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame,touchPoint))
        {
            //start inflating view animation
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.frame = inflatedFrame;

            }];

            hasExpanded = YES;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame,touchPoint))
        {
            //start deflating view animation
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.frame = initialFrame;

            }];

            hasExpanded = NO;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *singleTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [singleTouch locationInView:self.superview];
    [self inflateByCheckingPoint:touchPoint];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *singleTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [singleTouch locationInView:self.superview];
    [self inflateByCheckingPoint:touchPoint];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self forceDeflate];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self forceDeflate];
}

@end
```