# how to resolve “Type of expression in ambiguous without more context”? in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
func setTimeLeft() { let timeNow = NSDate() {

    if timeEnd.compare(timeNow as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let components = calendar.components([.day , .hour , .minute , .second]  , fromDate: timeNow, toDate: timeEnd, options: [])

        var dayText = String(components.day) + "d "
        var hourText = String(components.hour) + "h "

        // Hide day and hour if they are zero
        if components.day <= 0 {
            dayText = ""
            if components.hour <= 0 {
                hourText = ""
            }
        }
        timeLeftLabel.text = dayText + hourText + String(components.minute) + "m " + String(components.second) + "s"

    } else {
        timeLeftLabel.text = "Ended"
    }
}
```

i'm newbie and i just stuck at this error
error at line

```
let components = calendar.components([.day , .hour , .minute , .second]  , fromDate: timeNow, toDate: timeEnd, options: [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) instead of `NSCalendar` because `NSCalendar.current` will also give `Calendar` instance and then get `DateComponents` from calendar using `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` method.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day , .hour , .minute , .second], from: timeNow, to: timeEnd)
```

Comment: @Bilal Have you replace your code with my one, What is the error?, Can you show the screen shot if possible. Note that there is no option parameter  in this method.

Comment: @Bilal Welcome mate :)

Comment: Nirav do will still use NSDate() in swift 3.0 or we use Date()?

Comment: @Bilal You can use `NSDate` but it is batter if you use native `Date` because all swift's `Foundation` function need `Date` type as argument not `NSDate`.

Comment: can u help me again 
i want to give one standard time to timeEnd 
right now i'm doing this
 let timeEnd = Date(timeInterval:  7 * 60 * 60, since: Date() as Date)
so every time i open this view controller it start from 0 
i want something like 
 let timeEnd = Date(timeInterval:  28 Feb 2017 , since: Date() as Date)
that it end on a specific date like i mentioned above

Comment: @Bilal Don't get you, can you add new question here with specific detail and give me the link of it here, That would be easy to understand your issue.

Comment: i'm asking about this same question, at the very first line i'm using timeEnd variable and comparing it with timeNow , i declared timeEnd above  in code as let timeEnd = Date(timeInterval:  7 * 60 * 60, since: Date() as Date) but i want something like this let timeEnd = Date(timeInterval: 28 feb 2017 ,  since: Date() as Date) i want to end time on specific/mentioned/given date because right count down began everytime i switched to the viewcontroller where defined this time limit

Comment: @Bilal You want to create timeEnd to be date of 28 feb 2017 from string?

Comment: i want that time end keep running till the date that i provided/given time it to be , right now it only run when i switched to view controller where i mentioned this code

Comment: @Bilal You want to change the label's value continuously, right?\

Comment: yes ,any date ...that i wrote that ending date and when date finished or passed then label shows "time ended"

Comment: like if i give 28 feb 2017 as end date then at 12:00 am of  1 march 2017 label shows "time ended"

Comment: @Bilal Then you need to use timer like this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374553/how-to-make-a-countdown-with-nstimer-on-swift. and call your function with timer.

Comment: no , i want something like 
let timeEnd = Date(  26 feb 2017)//ending time, 
let timeNow = Date() // current time, 
 if timeEnd.compare(timeNow as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending  ,
i want to end this timer on 26 feb from current date either i run my app or not but timer kept runing and if i run my app on 27 feb it show "time ended"

Comment: @Bilal Really don't get you.

Comment: @Bilal Welcome mate:)