# Getting Error in Date Components

Tags: swift, datepicker, calendar

I'm using date component to get user's age but I'm getting error.
Can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
var components: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: datePicker.date, to: Date)
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Similar question is asked here:

[how to resolve “Type of expression in ambiguous without more context”? in swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246152/how-to-resolve-type-of-expression-in-ambiguous-without-more-context-in-swift)

but it did not work for me.

Comment: The last argument should be some `date` and not  `Date` (which is a type). You probably want `..., to: Date())`

Comment: @MartinR can you please explain more

Comment: To get the current date you need to create an instance of `Date` without any parameters, which is what @MartinR thinks you want there as the last parameter. So use `Date()` there instead of `Date`.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters of a function should be instances of classes and not class names:

```
var components: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: datePicker.date, to: Date())
```

If we refer to the library definition of this function:

> public func dateComponents(_ components: Set, from
>   start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents

`Date` is the type of the argument to be passed to this function. Calculating the age of a user is the result of calculating the date difference from their birthday (`datePicker.date`, which is an instance if `Date`) and now (`Date()`, which is also an instance if `Date`).