# Setting iPhone’s timer in Apple’s clock app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11

Is there an API to set a timer in Apple's Clock app to a specific countdown?

I know there is the Reminders SDK and EventKit, but I was looking for setting the timer and not a reminder.

[image: Timer in the Clock app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no available API for this.** You should create a custom timer inside your app to replicate that functionality.

Use the [**Timer**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) class of **Foundation** to make a simple timer in your application.

```
let timer: Timer!

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: false) { timer in
    [completion code]
}
```

For more information about creating a timer with a countdown, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29374553/3151675).