# how to get last cells and load more data from api

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with how the last cell appears in the table as well as loading more cells through the API

I would also like to add the Gray Activity Indicator At the bottom of the cells in the queue while loading the cells

Use Alamofire library
Swift 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gray Activity Indicator At the bottom add a custom cell with a Activity indicator along with a label stating "fetching more..........." or else show like below

**To Add Activity indicator in tableview**

```
func showIndicator() {
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

    spinner.startAnimating()
    tableView.backgroundView = spinner
}
```

**To get last cells and load more data from api**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         if yourArr.count-1 == indexPath.row{
            getMoreImages(page)
         }
 }

    func getMoreImages(page:Int){ 
       //hit api
       if api_success == true {
           if self.page == 0 {
              self.yourArr.removeAll()
           }
       self.yourArr.appendContentsOf(api_data)
       self.tableView.reloadData()
       self.page = self.page + 1
       }
    }
```

Comment: how to set CountdownLabel pod in label

I can't display the timer in the text You have implemented all the instructions on the website I want to put a timer for 24 hours only

Have you seen web site pod in github https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel?

This code did not work! ::

Comment: let countdownLabel = CountdownLabel(frame: CGRect.zero, minutes: 60*60*60)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer.text = countdownLabel.text
        countdownLabel.animationType = .Pixelate
        countdownLabel.start()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var timer: UILabel!

Comment: @iyas seyam - will you explain me this in detail i can't get you, if possible create a question feed with the code so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: @iyas seyam - upto this i believe the countdown label liberary you used is not working

Comment: Is there a countdown timer pod ?

Comment: For countdown timer pod, You could choose based on your design needs and swift version from the below link, 

github.com/topics/countdown-timer?l=swift

Comment: Sorry for the delay you could refer the below link for simple countdown flow, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374553/how-can-i-make-a-countdown-with-nstimer

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using the tableview delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This delegate method is called before tableview uses cell to draw a row which allows us to customise the cell before being displayed.
In this override method we get indexPath which can be used to check if the cell is the last one.