# Swift how to check if timer is done using time from certain variable?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm working on an a timer app which takes in two variables as times for the timer periodOneTime and periodTwoTime. Once the time is up on one periodOneTime, I want my app to switch to the periodTwoTime, and back and forth for my timer.

The variable timeLeft under the function **secondTimer** is holding these variables to check if the timer is up, and I need a way to check if the time on periodOneTime and periodTwoTime is up so I can switch to the next time. I've no idea where to start on this. Thanks for any help!

```
  @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    periodOneTime = Int(periodOne.text!)!
    periodTwoTime = Int(periodTwo.text!)!

    timeLeft = periodOneTime

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func stopTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timeRemaining.text = "0"
}

@objc func onTimerFires()
{
    timeLeft -= 1
    timeRemaining.text = String(timeLeft)

    if timeLeft <= 0 {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    //checks if time left is 0, then stops and starts second timer from periodTwo
    if timeLeft == 0 {
        timer?.invalidate()
        secondTimer()
    }
}
//Function to switch to second timer (periodTwo)
func secondTimer(){

    if timeLeft < 1{
        timeLeft = periodTwoTime
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

}
```

Comment: why?  What are you trying to achieve with the two timers?  If the first timer is just so that you can update a display, while the second one is the 'real' timer, this has been demonstrated lots of places - like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374553/how-can-i-make-a-countdown-with-nstimer

Comment: My dad wants a running app where he can set a time for himself to run, and once that time elapses he wants the second timer to run so he has a certain amount of time to walk, and back and forth. I am building the app for him.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - and you’re going about it the right way I think - when the first timer finishes use that to trigger the next one.  If you want a timer display, you need another one running to drive the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this, using a single timer which you use to update a display, and just keep track of whether you are running or walking - something like this

```
@IBAction func cmdStartStopAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    durationTimerDisplay = 0.1 // this will update the display every 0.1 seconds
    currentlyRunning = true // assume we start by running

    if timerDisplay == nil // this means we are starting the timer
    {
        durationRun = Double(txtTimerRun.text!)!    // assumes you have a text box to enter the times
        durationWalk = Double(txtTimerWalk.text!)!

        durationRemaining = durationRun             // we can use this to display a countdown timer

        // start the display update timer
        timerDisplay = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: durationTimerDisplay, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerDisplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else
    {
        timerDisplay.invalidate()
        timerDisplay = nil
    }
}

@objc func onTimerDisplay()
{
    durationRemaining -= durationTimerDisplay       // count down timer
    if durationRemaining <= 0                       // switch between running and walking when you reach zero
    {
        // switch from running to walking, or walking to running
        currentlyRunning = !currentlyRunning
        if currentlyRunning {
            durationRemaining = durationRun
        }
        else {
            durationRemaining = durationWalk
        }
    }

    // create a display using a label lblTimer
    if currentlyRunning {
        lblTimer.text = String(format: "RUN: %.1f", durationRemaining)
    }
    else {
        lblTimer.text = String(format: "WALK: %.1f", durationRemaining)
    }
}
```